# DynamicResource Cannot be resolved

Tags: wpf

I have been trying to learn about resources and styles, I want to create a chromeless window.

I have an example that acheives what I want via the following simple extracts of xaml.

I have a Resource set in Themes/Generic.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="BorderlessWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
</Style>
```

I have a main window:

```
<Window x:Class="Project1.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project1"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="Shell" Height="576" Width="1024" Style="{DynamicResource BorderlessWindowStyle}">
<Grid></Grid>
```

But the style is not being applied and VS designer states it cannot resolve the resource.

The example I have been looking at does things this way and I cannot discover the difference between what I have seen done and what I am trying to do.

I thought that Genric.xaml was a 'special' resource dictionary that should be discoverable by my Window control - and I am guessing this assumption is my error.

What do I need to do to make this work? (Now I understand I can set these properties in the Window xaml directly, and I have done so and get the effect I want. BUT I really want to undersatnd using the Generic.xaml resource dictionary way as I have presented here)

best regards

John.

Comment: Have you tried running your program; does that work? It could be that VS designer is limited in this aspect, because DynamicResources are evaluated at runtime as opposed to at compile time.

Comment: Yes I did run the app but the style was not applied.

Comment: Try changing Generic.xaml to generic.xaml

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either.  To initially create the Generic.xaml I created a custom control so that Visual studio would add it for me, then deleted the unwanted custom control.  I did this to remove any possibility of human error.

Comment: I added this to App.xaml <Application.Resources> and now it works.

I thought that for Generic.xaml this was not required. I'm a little confused.

<ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/generic.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Themes/generic.xaml file is automatically used to find default styles for Custom Controls. In your case you have an ordinary Window with custom style. You cannot define this style in `Window.Resources` section, because the style should be defined at a higher level. The only higher level of Window is App.xaml, because the Window is in fact its child. That's why the solution for your question is to place the style into `App.Resources` section.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would add the following example in case it helps some others out.  To add a resource dictionary to your app.xaml file you can add the following xaml code to the app.xaml file.

```
<Application x:Class="ProjectX.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectX"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Use the Black skin by default -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\ResourceFile.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Where 'Resources' coudl be a folder in your project that contains the Resource Dictionary file (ResourceFile.xaml).

The you can add code to your resource dictionary like such:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectX.Resources">

<!-- The Background Brush is used as the background for the Main Window -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainBackgroundBrush" Color="#FF202020" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And then finally, dynamically bind to your resource dictionary doing something like:

```
<Window
  x:Class="ProjectX.MainWindow"
  Title="Family.Show" Height="728" Width="960"
  Background="{DynamicResource MainBackgroundBrush}"
  ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
</Window>
```